# Nginx server works only locally

Tags: nginx, web-server, website, vultr

I have set up a VPS on Vultr running Debian 10, and I've just installed `nginx`.

If my understanding is correct, at this stage, I should be able to see something like

[image]

when I visit my website. Indeed, when I run `curl -i mydomain.com` from the ssh terminal (i.e., from `root@mydomain.com`), I see the html for the above webpage in the terminal, but when I run it from another terminal (or just my browser), I get no response.

I have read other answers to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473064/cant-be-accessed-from-outside-the-local-server-using-nginx) on this site which point to Firewall blocking port 80, but there is no Firewall set up from the Vultr side. Also, these are the records I currently have on my DNS:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server, install a firewall, then allow traffic to the Nginx server.

```
sudo apt install ufw -y && sudo systemctl enable ufw && sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

UFW is the package "uncomplicated firewall". By installing the firewall and granting access to 'Nginx Full', it should open access to your server, whereas right now, it's probably rejecting everything. We'll know after you try it and reply back.

Comment: Can you explain how/why this would help? Or link to an authoritative reference that suggests it? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I will try this and let you know what happens.

Comment: I just visited the IP. You're good to go. I see the Nginx page.